# Bitwise operator on a large unsigned integers (>1024bit) in SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, bit-manipulation

I am writing a query that looks something like this:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM lists 
  WHERE ((1 << lists.index_number) & :fingerprint_value) = (1 << lists.index_number) 
  AND lists.list_id = :listid;
```

However, bitwise operators work up to 64bit unsigned integers, but I have to work with 1024bit unsigned integers. Maybe even larger values in the future. So does anyone have any idea how I could approach the same thing but with bigger unsigned integers/binary values?

Comment: Mysql 8 can worl with bigint and Blob so 1024 bit shouldn't be a problem.https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/bit-functions.html

Comment: I see I can't read apparently. I had that page open and read it as working only up to 64bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I cannot read,

Starting from Mysql 8 bitwise operators can be used and the query in the question should work fine.